# How to match a specific string with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string

```
var txt="[!Qtextara1] Description1 [@Qtextara1]
        [!Qtextarea2] Description2 [@Qtextarea2]"
```

I want to match this string using regular expression
The output should something like this.

```
{Qtextara1: Description1,  Qtextarea2: Description2}
```

Is it possible with regular expression? Please help me..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't strings be enclosed in quotes?

Comment: Yes, the string enclosed in quotes.

Comment: What do you really need to match? the [!TEXT]? the TEXT? [@TEXT]? Everything? What is dynamic?

Comment: The whole string is dynamic. [!Qtextara1] is the key and Description1 is its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
\[\!([\s\S]+?)\]\s+([\s\S]+?)\s*\[@\1\]
```

Explanation:

- `\[\!` - Match literal `[!`
- `([\s\S]+?)` - Capture group 1 to match 1 or more characters inside `[]` (the tag name, we'll need that later on)
- `\]\s+` - Literal `]` and 1 or more whitespace symbols
- `([\s\S]+?)` - Capture group 2 to capture (even multiline) description
- `\s*\[@\1\]` - Match 0 or more whitespace, followed by a literal `[@`, then a backreference to the first capture group (the tag name), and then a literal `]`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB9fZ4/1).

```js
var re = /\[\!([\s\S]+?)\]\s+([\s\S]+?)\s*\[@\1\]/g; 
var test_str = '[!Qtextara1] Long Description Wi[th%^&*\n(Abra# $]Cadabra~!~## 1 [@Qtextara1]\n        [!Qtextarea2] Description2 [@Qtextarea2]';
 
while ((m = re.exec(test_str)) !== null) {
    alert(m[1] + ", " + m[2])
}
```

Comment: Can you explain? I tested a regexp but it's twice longer.

Comment: Awesome stribizhev.. A small issue.. Some time "Description1" is a long text and it has spaces, something like "Desc ript ion 1". In that condition it is not working..

Comment: Looks like it is working now. It even supports multiline descriptions. Thank you for an interesting question, BTW, but please add your attempts to the question body.

Comment: @romuleald: I added a description. In JS, to match text across several lines, we need to use `[\s\S]+`, it is a well-known to SO regex people trick.

Answer (score 0):

I got this

```
txt.match(/(\[\![a-zA-Z0-9]*\]) ([a-zA-Z0-9]*) (\[\@[a-zA-Z0-9]*\])/);
```

That split in 3 part:

**Part 1**:

```
txt.match(/(\[\![a-zA-Z0-9]*\]) ([a-zA-Z0-9]*) (\[\@[a-zA-Z0-9]*\])/)[1];
"[!Qtextara1]"
```

**Part 2**:

```
txt.match(/(\[\![a-zA-Z0-9]*\]) ([a-zA-Z0-9]*) (\[\@[a-zA-Z0-9]*\])/)[2];
"Description1"
```

**Part 3**:

```
txt.match(/(\[\![a-zA-Z0-9]*\]) ([a-zA-Z0-9]*) (\[\@[a-zA-Z0-9]*\])/)[3];
"[@Qtextara1]"
```

But that could be greatly improved.